# SSLSCAN not getting executed properly after removing TLS1.0

Tags: ssl, kali-linux, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls

**STILL A NEWBIE TO UBUNTU , please excuse if its a silly one** . I posted this question on Askubuntu but someone suggested to post it here on superuser.com

I was asked to stop supporting TLS1.0 ciphers. Googled and found out that adding below line to ssl.conf can remove TLS1.0 from httpd :

```
SSLProtocol all -TLSv1
```

There is a "sslscan" on kali linux which I am using to scan the ip with port 443 to list the supported ciphers by that ip.

Now , before removing the TLS1.0 cipher SSLSCAN worked properly and gave proper results as below :

```
TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLS 1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.1 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.0  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  112 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 1024 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA

  Preferred Server Cipher(s):
TLSv1.0  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256

  SSL Certificate:
"SSL Certificate details , I think is confidential to my organization so not sharing it"
```

After REMOVING TLS1.0 CIPHERS SSLSCAN results are below:

```
TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLS 1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.1 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA        Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA

  Preferred Server Cipher(s):
TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256

Failed to connect to get certificate.
```

Why after removing the TLS1.0 ciphers , sslscan is not able to connect to get certificates ? Am I removing TLS1.0 wrongly ? If yes , what is the correct way of disabling/removing TLS1.0 ciphers ? Or is it normal ? Does sslscan uses only TLS1.0 to scan the ip with port 443 which I had disabled i.e y it is failing to get certificate ?

Incase if somebody wants to have a look on this question on Askubuntu , here is the link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/819568/sslscan-not-getting-executed-properly-after-removing-tls1-0

Comment: Don't confuse _protocols_ and _ciphers_. For example, the TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 protocols use mostly the same ciphers. Your `SSLProtocol` is the correct approach, but I _think_ you might need `-TLSv1.0` instead? Just a guess.

Comment: So you meen to say that ... by above method i am restricting TLS1.0 ciphers as well as TLS1.1 ciphers ? Coz both of them use almost same set of ciphers and I am restricting the protocol itself ? And for restricting TLS1.0 ciphers only i need to use somewhat like " SSLProtocol all -TLSv1.0 " as I only need to restrict TLS1.0 ciphers or it is not possible at all to restrict only TLS1.0 ciphers somehow and allow TLS1.1? Please excuse if that as an obvious thing or i misunderstood it.

Comment: You do not want to restrict ciphers.  You want to restrict _protocols_.

Comment: @grawity : Okay , for restricting protocol TLS1.0 "-TLSv1" should be used i think. Followed below link :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html
.But after restricting it SSLSCAN is failing to connect to get the certificate , is it normal ?